# Swift convert Unix timestamp to Date with timezone and save it to EKEvent

Tags: swift, nsdate, eventkit

I trying to convert my unix timestamp(Int) to the Date type in my app. I found a solution which is

```
let str = timeValue as? NSNumber
return Date(timeIntervalSince1970: str.doubleValue)
```

This solution works but how can I set the timezone. I found another solution that used the formatter but the formatter return string.

```
func convertDateTime(timeValue: Int) -> String {
    let truncatedTime = Int(timeValue)
    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: TimeInterval(truncatedTime))
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT+8")
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"

    return formatter.string(from: date)
}
```

Anyone can answer me how to do so?

Edited: I want to save it as `EKEvent`.

Comment: You can't "set the timezone" of a `Date`. `Date`s do not contain timezones. That's why you have to make it a string.

Comment: @Sweeper so I should make it as a string then convert back the `Date` ?

Comment: No, that would lose the timezone information. Stop thinking of `Date`s as a tuple of year, month, day, hour, minute, second and timezone. They represent _instants of time_. A `DateFormatter` tells you what an instant of time is _called_ (its string representation) in a given timezone.

Comment: So the real question is, why do you want to set the timezone? Do you want to display it to the user? If so, use a string. Do you want to store the timezone info in DB? If so, get a `TimeZone` object and store its `identifier`.

Comment: @Sweeper basically I have an object that contained a unix timestamp, so I got a function that store the object into the Calendar using the eventkit. That function using Date() to store. So I'm confusing now. I just want to convert unix to Date() and with the correct timezone.

Comment: In that case, there is [`EKCalendarItem.timeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekcalendaritem/1507104-timezone). Set it to your favourite `TimeZone`! But remember, `Date` is always an instant in time, without a timezone.

Comment: @Sweeper Its work! Thank you for explaining about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date`s represent instants/points in time - "x seconds since a reference point". They are not "x seconds since a reference point *at a location*", so the timezone is not part of them. It makes no sense to "set the timezone of a `Date`", the same way it makes no sense to "set the number of decimal places of a `Double`".

It seems like you actually want to store a `EKCalendarEvent`. Well, `EKCalendarEvent`s *do* have a timezone, because they are events that occur at a particular instant/day ([`occurrenceDate`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekevent/1507244-occurrencedate)), in some timezone ([`timeZone`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/ekcalendaritem/1507104-timezone)). So you just need to set the `timeZone` property of the `EKEvent`, rather than the `Date`.